# Navigation property from dependent to principal

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

I have two Entities

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

in my business first we create person then we create an employee by selecting a person, while selecting person for the employee i want to select only the persons who are not associated to employee, i couldn't figure how to configure the Employee property in Person Entity

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting people that aren't related to a specific employee then you shouldn't have a property for that. You should only have link to related entities. Try doing this in LINQ it should get you all people that don't have a relation to an employee.

```
var people = context.People.Where(x => x.Employee == null);

public class Person
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
 }

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    [InverseProperty("Employee")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Think that should do it, inverse property creates the mapping so only needs to be done from one side.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: i don't have employee yet, i'm creating employee by selecting a person, and i want to exclude persons that already assigned to an employee, and also i don't use context directly, i'm dealing with repository

Comment: Ah so you want all people that don't have any employee?

Comment: this should work if i successfully configured the navigation property, but i couldn't, could you tell me how to do it in fluent API or data annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer, don't know if it's the best!

```
jobQuery = jobQuery.Where(jb => !Context.Employees.Any(emp => emp.JobId == jb.Id));
```